# ListView not scrolling on Android 7.1.1

Tags: android

I'm trying to deploy a ListView app on an Android 7.1.1 device. The list view contains enough items to exceed the size of the screen. Any layouting/code combination that I have tried so far has failed - there is no scrolling performed on the device.

Here is the latest layout excerpt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbarSize="3dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any hint would be appreciated.

Edit: The list view is built by an android.widget.ArrayAdapter and an android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 item layout:

```
itemsList = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
itemsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, new ArrayList<>(...items...)));
itemsList.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip 1: Use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`

Tip 2: Use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.html). It's much more flexible and modern then ListView.

Tip 3: There is no need for that LinearLayout, if there is just one view in it.

Hope some of these tips will fix your issue.

Comment: I had some leftover code to calculate the layout params of the ListView while still experimenting with a parent ScrollView. Removing that part, as well as changing the height to "match_parent" as you suggested, worked for me - thank you for the tips Šimon Vyhnis. Even seems to work now with a height of "fill_parent"